# CGContextSetShadowWithColor not showing on device

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have a custom UIView which is a rectangle with rounded corners a drop shadow and a small border.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //// General Declarations
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //// Shadow Declarations
    CGColorRef shadow = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.3].CGColor;
    CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    CGFloat shadowBlurRadius = 2;

    //// Abstracted Graphic Attributes
    CGRect roundedRectangleFrame = CGRectMake(2, 0, rect.size.width - 4, rect.size.height - 2);


    //// Rounded Rectangle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: roundedRectangleFrame cornerRadius: 2];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadowOffset, shadowBlurRadius, shadow);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [roundedRectanglePath fill];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    [[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:0.3] setStroke];
    roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth = 0.5;
    [roundedRectanglePath stroke];
}
```

My problem is that in the simulator everything is perfectly rendered but when I run the code on a device (I use a iPod touch 4 Generation) it only renders the rounded corner rectangle and the border but no shadow. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried with a bigger shadow?

Comment: Yes I tried no matter how big I make it it will show on the device, even tried using red color.

Comment: Are you drawing outside of your bounds? I.e. is the shadow being clipped?

Comment: It is drawn inside the bounds and it shows perfectly when I run the code in the simulator but it does not show when I run on the device.

Comment: @Larme hinted at this already, but I'd suggest looking more carefully at device pixel ratio issues. That is, do you have the same problem as you do on your device if you set the simulator to a Retina resolution?

Comment: Yes I tried various shadow sizes and simulator resolutions. I think might have something to do with how Mac and iOS handle CGReferences because sometimes the app crashed when trying to apply the shadow when running on the device. I got rid of the reference and for the moment the problem is "solved".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already found your solution, but I will explain why your original code did not work and why your solution works.

You are using ARC, which means the compiler automatically manages the lifetime of Objective-C objects for you.  But the compiler does not know about or manage the lifetime of Core Foundation objects.  Your original code says this:

```
CGColorRef shadow = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.3].CGColor;
```

When you call `+[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:]`, it returns a reference to a `UIColor` object.  You immediately send the `CGColor` message to the `UIColor` object, getting a `CGColorRef`.

Since you don't use the `UIColor` object later in the method, the compiler thinks it is safe to release the `UIColor` object immediately at the end of that statement.  Releasing the `UIColor` there deallocates it.  When it's deallocated, the `UIColor` object releases the `CGColor` object.  Since you didn't claim ownership of the `CGColor` object, that release deallocates the `CGColor` object.  By the time you get to the `CGContextSetShadowWithColor` statement, the memory that contained the `CGColor` object is in an unknown state.

Your solution fixes the problem by embedding the `+[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:]` message into the statement that uses the `CGColor` object.  So by the time the statement ends and the `UIColor` is released and deallocated, you've already handed the `CGColor` off to the graphics context, which retains it, preventing it from being deallocated.

That's the way I would fix the problem, too.  But there are other ways.  One other way is to claim ownership of the `CGColor` object explicitly:

```
CGColorRef shadow = CGColorRetain([UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0
    green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.3].CGColor);

...

CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadowOffset, shadowBlurRadius, shadow);
CGColorRelease(shadow);
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice and detailed explanation. I had no clue that ARC does not know how to handle CF objects, although I was always sceptical about the "magic" ARC was doing under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I can´t really explain why  but instead of using a CGColorRef using the UIColor expression itself "solved" the problem. Now it renders perfect in all resolutions in the simulator as well as on the device.

The now working code looks like this:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
//// General Declarations
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//// Shadow Declarations
CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
CGFloat shadowBlurRadius = 2;

//// Abstracted Graphic Attributes
CGRect roundedRectangleFrame = CGRectMake(2, 0, rect.size.width - 4, rect.size.height - 2);


//// Rounded Rectangle Drawing
UIBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: roundedRectangleFrame cornerRadius: 2];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadowOffset, shadowBlurRadius, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.3].CGColor);
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
[roundedRectanglePath fill];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

[[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:0.3] setStroke];
roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth = 0.5;
[roundedRectanglePath stroke];
```

}